# Use other sbt commands than "sbt run" in the "sbt-native-packager" script. For example: "sbt flywayMigrate"

Tags: command, sbt, packaging, flyway, sbt-native-packager

I'm currently trying to package a project containing "Flyway" using the "sbt-native-packager" and the "universal" plug-in. The problem is, that the script of the packaged project only uses the "sbt run" command of SBT. But I need it to run commands like "sbt flywayMigrate" or "sbt flywayClean" from "Flyway" on it.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe Customizing the "run" command or add other commands to the script?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Native-packager doesn't use "sbt run", but creates a runnable distribution. You can however override the `mainClass in Compile` if you have multiple main classes:

`mainClass in Compile := Some("com.example. MyMain")`

You can run flyway programmatically. There is also a play plugin if you are using play.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it programmatically!